# Sitecore dynamic data source locations

Tags: sitecore, datasource

I have some components in my Sitecore install that can be added to one of any multiple placeholders on a page. The data source location of the renderings of these components can change based on what placeholder they are added to the site. I started creating a processor like

```
<getRenderingDatasource>
        <processor patch:after="*[@type='custom']"  type="custom" />
</getRenderingDatasource>
```

The class is like

```
public class GetDynamicDataSourceLocations : GetDatasourceLocation
    {
        public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
        {
            ...            
        }
    }
```

I can't get the placeholder that I'm trying to attach the rendering to. Is there any way I can get the placeholder or atleast the parent where the component is being added?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. The args for that pipeline  assume thatthe datasource location is fixed. And I don't think there's any contextual information to latch on to. Interesting idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good idea you have here, but the `GetRenderingDatasourceArgs` can't provide you with the data you need if you're configuring the allowed datasource locations on the placeholder.

I've searched through querystring & form variables and context items as well, but there is no reference to the placeholder available in the `getRenderingDatasource` pipeline.

I did come up with something that could be the solution, although it's a bit hacky.

1. Create a processor for the `getPlaceholderRenderings`. The `GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs` will provide you with a placeholder key.
2. Store the key in a session variable (I don't know another way of transferring data between pipelines at this point)
3. Retrieve the key from the session in your `getRenderingDatasource` processor.

This is the code I used to test it:

```
// Add to the getRenderingDatasource pipeline.
public class GetPlaceholderKey
{
    public void Process(GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs args)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Placeholder"] = args.PlaceholderKey;
    }
}

// Add to the getRenderingDatasource pipeline.
public class GetAllowedDatasources
{
    public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Placeholder"]);
    }
}
```

This works when you add a rendering to a placeholder, but I have not tested other scenarios.
I can imagine it would not work when you set the datasource of a rendering that is already placed in the placeholder.

Comment: R.e. 2) you might be able to use HttpContext.Items instead of session.